# Edit html in cypress

Tags: cypress

Is there a way to make cypress change the html of a page.

I am trying to make a test for a vulnerability on my site however the vulnerability requires the user to change a tag on a html element. Is there a way to make cypress do this?

the element is a checkbox and it is disabled, however what i want cypress to do is remove the disabled tag and then click the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled>
```

then i want cypress to remove the disabled tag so it is

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `removeAttr` to remove the disabled tag. Something like:

```js
cy.get('input[type="checkbox"]').invoke('removeAttr', 'disabled')
```